# coloring 3D plots on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, surf

I made two 3D plots on the same axis. now I desire to give them different colors for easy identification. How do I do this coloring?  The MATLAB code is shown below.

```
tic
Nx = 50;
Ny = 50;
x = linspace(0,1,Nx);
y = linspace(0,0.5,Ny);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
[M,N] = size(X);
 for m=1:M
    for n=1:N
        %get x,y coordinate
        x_mn = X(m,n);
        y_mn = Y(m,n);
        %%% X=D2   and Y=D1
        %Check if x_mn and y_mn satisfy requirement
        if(x_mn >= y_mn)
            %evaluate function 1
           Z(m,n) =  (x_mn^2 - 2*x_mn*y_mn + y_mn^2);
           Z_1(m,n) =  (x_mn^2);
        elseif(x_mn < y_mn)
            %evaluate function 2
            Z(m,n) =  0;
            Z_1(m,n) =  (x_mn^2);
            %% Z(m,n) = 2*(2*x_mn*y_mn + y_mn - y_mn^2 - 2*x_mn);
        else 
            Z(m,n) = 0;
       
        end
    end
end
%Plot the surface
figure
surf(X,Y,Z)   %first plot
surfc(X,Y,Z)
hold on
surf(X,Y,Z_1)   %second plot
xlabel('Dm');
ylabel('D');
zlabel('pR');
grid on
shading interp
toc
disp('DONE!')
```

How can I create two differently colored surfaces?

Comment: For future questions: please read [mcve]. This is a rather non-minimal example with a lot of info (the nested `for` loops for instance) which is not relevant to the question. All you need is `x=1:100;y=1:00;z=rand(100);figure;surf(x,y,z)` to demonstrate your problem. Reducing a piece of your code to an actual MINIMAL example helps you to home in on the problem and helps others to quickly determine what's up, rather than having to read lines and lines of unrelated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
figure
surf(X,Y,Z)   %first plot
surfc(X,Y,Z)
hold on
surf(X,Y,Z_1)
```

Your `surfc()` call actually overwrites your `surf()` call, is this intended?

As to your colour: the [documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surfc.html) is a marvellous thing:

> `surfc(X,Y,Z,C)` additionally specifies the surface color.

In other words: just specify the colour as you want it. `C` needs to be a matrix of `size(Z)` with the desired colours, i.e. set all of them equal to create an monocoloured surface:

```matlab
x = 1:100;
y = 1:100;
z = rand(100);

figure;
surfc(x,y,z,ones(size(z)))
hold on
surfc(x,y,z+6,ones(size(z))+4)
```

Results in (MATLAB R2007b, but the syntax is the same nowadays)

[image]